# Angled brackets for type annotation in Dart changing to incorrect color per theme in VSCode

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, brackets

[image]

Theme angled brackets color is green but being overridden with bracket from different "font" and color white. Occurs with other themes like Monokai that colorize angle brackets.

[image]

[image]

These are the inspected editor token scopes.

It changes once the brackets are closed.

Comment: find the difference in TextMate Scope of the 2 angled brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the textmate grammar used for syntax highlighting is fairly simple and regex based. It doesn't have access to semantics and detects unmatched `<` as a less-than operator.

Without semantics, the code is a little ambiguous - for example consider this code:

```
final List = 1;
final String = 2;
List<String;
```

Here, the `<` really is a less-than operator, but because the textmate grammar is fairly simple regex, it doesn't know the difference.

That said, it might be possible to compensate for this in the semantic tokens by having them always produce some token for the `<` and `>` in type args. I've filed an issue at https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3668 to take a look at this.

---

Edit: Turns out this wasn't possible to fix reliably in semantic tokens either, as there's a lot of code that is still ambiguous. For example:

```
main() {
  List<String
}
```

Is parsed with `List<String` being an expression (not type args). Therefore I'm going to leave this as-is.

Comment: Ah ok I see. Thanks Dan. It was just always green so was out of the ordinary. I also noticed you updated the angled brackets handling via this issue https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3633 so that might've made the change

Comment: Yeah, I initially thought that change might've been the cause, although re-reading it I'm not so sure. I'd never seen this issue before as the themes I use didn't color less-than/greater-than differently. It's unfortunate it looks odd like this, although since it's incomplete code I think it's a little understandable. Ofcourse if complete/valid code appears incorrect, it definitely should be possible to improve.